# Using RFID-RC522 with spi on RBpi 3B+

Tags: python, spi, rfid

Hello_friends,

I am trying to get a RFID reader working on a Raspberry 3b+

That same setup and codebase used to work well on the older 3b+ model from 2015 (the current one is 2017 edition), but now everything had to be re-installed, so maybe the problem is due to a outdated lib or something?

The module spi is found and included in my script, but as soon as it tries to `openSPI()`, I encounter

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openSPI'`

This leaves me in a bit of a hassle since everything worked fine in the past and nothing was changed on the codebase.

I already confirmed that SPI is activated and found by the means of `lsmod` and by looking into `/dev/` -> everything shows up, also I confirmed that nothing is blacklisted and the spi is turned on in the boot config. We tested and tried for multiple hours now, also we use the 2873 version of the module since the old 2807 seems to be outdated.

How can I debug or solve this? I am sure that the SPI module is included since I printed out the module and had something in the likes of

`[/path/to/lib/spi/__init__]` printed there ( can't confirm the exact path atm )
on the old one the print gave `[/path/to/lib/spi.so]` back.

The init in the first one calls the SPIdev and fails, the second one seems to be a compiled binary that works out of the box.

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: `3b+ model from 2015 (the current one is 2017 edition),` ... what makes you believe that the problem is caused by hardware? ... are you running exactly the same software?

Comment: For newer OS versions after stretch, we no longer need to use "openSPI'".